# Illumination of light on wall

Tags: trigonometry

A search light rotating from point $P$ is positioned $50$m from two walls that are opposite eachother. The walls is long enough to make the light almost invisible at each end. The illumination of the light is represented by the equation $d = 50\sec(2\pi t)$, where d is the distance, in metres, from the light to the wall, and t is time, in minutes.

1. If the effective distance for the light is $100$m, how many seconds elapse before the wall is not illuminated sufficiently?
2. How many seconds does it then take for the light to become effective on the opposite wall?
3. Determine how many meters of each wall are effectively illuminated as the light rotates.

I've been working on this question for a while now and I'm still having a lot of trouble understanding what I have to do. For part 1 I tried setting $d = 100$, but I don't know what to do after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by drawing a picture of where is the light with respect to the walls. It will help you understand the problem. At $t=0$, the light points toward one of the walls. As it starts to rotate, the light spot moves along the wall, and the distance between the spot and the light increases. When the distance is 100m, you cannot see the spot on the wall anymore. So you set $d=100$, and you calculate $t_1$. You then need to transform this from minutes to seconds.

For part 2, your light continues to rotate, and after a while the light will point towards the second wall. When the distance from the light to the spot on the second wall is once again 100, you get a time $t_2$. What the problem asks is what is $t_2-t_1$.

For part 3, the drawing will help again. Draw the light pointing toward one of the walls. The distance between the light and the spot is 50m. As you rotate, the distance between the light and the spot increases, until you get to $d=100$m. Draw this position. The wall and the two directions now form a right angle triangle. One of the sides is 50m, and the hypotenuse is 100m. You need to find the other side. Just note that this is only half of the distance, as you can see if you draw the next time the light hits the same wall.

Comment: Thank you for the response! When I set $d = 100$, I got $100 = 50\sec(2\pi t)$. I simplified that to $2 = sec(2\pi t)$, but how do I solve for $t$ from that? When I try punching in $1/arccos(2)$ on my calculator it gives me an error.

Comment: $2=\sec(2\pi t)$ means $\cos(2\pi t)=1/2$

Comment: Just to double check, I ended up with 1/6 minutes, or 10 seconds as my answer for both part 1 and part 2. Is that what you got?

Comment: yes for part 1. For the second wall, you need to use some symmetry and periodicity considerations to rewrite the formula for $d$. And I get $t_2=2/6$ minutes, so the interval is also 10 seconds